# "Undefined reference" error in Qt Creator

Tags: qt, qt-creator, undefined-reference

I'm trying to import some working Visual C++ code into Qt Creator and I'm having some compilation error I can't explain. This is my code:

```
// TabSprite.h

#include <GraphicsItem.h>

namespace appetizer {

class TabSprite : public GraphicsItem {

public:

  TabSprite(GraphicsWindow* parentWindow);

}
```

---

```
// TabSprite.cpp

#include <TabSprite.h>
using namespace appetizer;

TabSprite::TabSprite(GraphicsWindow* parentWindow): GraphicsItem(parentWindow) {

}
```

And Qt Creator give me this error (at the constructor declaration in `TabSprite.cpp`):

> Undefined reference to 'appetizer::GraphicsItem::GraphicsItem(appetizer::GraphicsWindow*)

However `GraphicsItem` is properly declared in `GraphicsItem.h` so I don't understand why the compilers doesn't find it. Can anybody see what could be wrong with this code?

Comment: BTW: afaik there's a difference between defining and declaring: In TabSprite.h you declare the ctor of TabSprite and in TabSprite.cpp you define it.

Comment: I clarified my code - i should indeed have written "declared" and not "defined". I still can't get the code to compile though.

Comment: And I think it's good practise to use `namespace appetizer { /* definition of TabSprite*/ }` rather than `using namespace` which is sometimes critical. And: It's not a compilation but a linker error

Comment: @Polybos, it could also be defined in TabSprite.h if it's inline. Should be fine either way, as long as it is defined somewhere.

Comment: If you want your name to appear please set it in your SO preferences.

Comment: @Sergey Tachenov: Of course, but I wanted to say where declaration in definition is in his case :)

Comment: @user561309, the error you gave is a linking error. So you can get it to compile, you can't get it to link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That means that you didn't define the constructor of `GraphicsItem`.

Comment: Sorry I didn't include the whole code: GraphicsItem is defined in GraphicsItem.h, which itself is included in TabSprite.h. I've updated the code to show that.

Comment: Oh well you were right actually. The GraphicsItem.h file was there but not included in the .pro file so it wasn't being compiled. Problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

The constructor is probably *declared* in TabSprite.h (although your code doesn't show that). That's why it compiles. But the constructor isn't *defined* anywhere, or, less likely, the unit where it is defined isn't included in the linking process. That's why it doesn't link.